# Android OCRSample using tesseract in Android

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

I want to make an application in that text is extracted and converted into another language like below app at time of camera is viewing like below screen shot of below app in play store [CamDictionary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intsig.camdict)

Below is the screen shot

[image]

Look in this camera is scanning and translating is done at real time **can anybody suggest me example like this**

I googled and find out one library

https://github.com/komamitsu/Android-OCRSample

but in that it suggested that

**checkout http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/ and copy traineddata file(s) into "/mnt/sdcard/ocrsample/tessdata/" on your Android like this:
adb push ~/src/tesseract-ocr-read-only/tessdata/eng.traineddata /mnt/sdcard/ocrsample/tessdata/**

I have searched out whole thing but there is no any file that should i have to put in **/mnt/sdcard/ocrsample/tessdata/** can any body suggest me what is that file because i have checkout following link

```
     svn checkout http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ tesseract-ocr-read-only
```

but it contain so many source code for windows app also and there is like more than 700 MB

i want just andorid files that should i have to put in SDCARD please any body help me

**is there any other solution than also please suggest me**

Comment: Not sure  see this https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/source/browse/trunk/tessdata/eng.traineddata

Comment: Here: https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list